# Windows 10 cannot start from GRUB after Ubuntu 17.10 installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, windows-10

So, let me explain my setup a bit.

I have a MacBook Pro (Early 2011) which I dual booted (Windows 10 and Mac OS). Then I decided I also needed Ubuntu, which I installed on an external disk.

And here's where things turned messy.

When the mac boots up, after pressing the Option button, I can see two options:

- One to load Mac OS (which works fine)
- "EFI Boot"

Selecting "EFI Boot" brings up GRUB, with the following options:

- Ubuntu
- Windows 10 (at /dev/sda1)

If I select Ubuntu it works fine.
If I select Windows 10, after a while, it throws me the message `File /efi/microsoft/boot/bootmgfw.efi not found`

I've read a few posts on the subject, and many suggested running `grub-update` from Ubuntu.

However, the weird thing is, `grub-update` seems to recognize Windows. It just doesn't work when selected from the boot menu.

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-21-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
done
```

What's going on? Any ideas?

Comment: Is Windows fast start up off? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Grub will not boot Windows if hibernated nor if it needs chkdsk. You then have to directly boot Windows (not sure if possible with Mac), not thru grub or use Windows repair disk.

Comment: @karel you were right, this did the trick ;)